# Reducing the dimension for partial string matching between two large files

Tags: svm, data-mining, text-mining, index-decomposition

I have two very large files, including POIs and have a tool that could do fuzzy matching between each pair of strings between these two files.
The problem is that, it is an `O(n^2)` problem. Is there any method that would reduce the complexity?